# Angular 5, MEAN, how do I limit API fetch requests to not more than 10 per min

Tags: angular, fetch-api, limit

As per title, how do I go about limiting the amount of API requests.
Is it possible to use a caching system so that when you reach the limit, the system returns the cache. Until you get below the limit again?

What would be the best way to do this?

```html
var marketCapURL = "https://api.xxx.xx"
const proxyurl3 = "https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/";   
const url3 = ""; // site that doesn’t send Access-Control-*
           fetch(proxyurl3 + marketCapURL) 
           .then(response => response.json())
           .then(contents => {  
            this.array = contents;
```

Comment: Maybe service workers.

Comment: Is there a reason why fetch is used instead of HttpClient? You will have better chances to solve it in a reasonable way if you will focus on HttpClient and RxJS instead, because this is the case for RxJS.

Comment: if I don't use fetch it keep throwing:  No ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ header is present, I used Cors on and off, and I will be using NGINX eventually so it will probably be ok to use HTTPclient then? Where would I start using Httpclient?

Comment: using `HttpClient` you can implement an `Intereceptor` which will allow you to monitor your API calls in one place, inject, modify, remove or add request details in one place and one place only.

Comment: Stavm I will flag you as correct answer. If you add it as answer thank u! I already had an interceptor in place but never used it sofar!